# Infragistics XamDataGrid with variable number of columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I need to be able to support a XamDataGrid which at design time will not have a set number of columns.  For example, the app will run, get some data from the server and create some objects.  Depending on the response from the server, I may have a different number of objects each time I run the app.

Here is an example of what I mean.  Lets say I make a call to some service and get back an xml response with some info.  I deserialize that response into a number of objects, which can be different each time the call is made.

Lets say each object has two properties, Label and Value.  I would like the grid to show columns with labels that match the value of Label with values from Value.  So if I have a two objects, obj1 and obj2, that look like this:

```
obj1.Label = "Parts"
obj1.Value = "17"

obj2.Label = "Parts"
obj2.Value = "12"
```

I would like a grid that looks like this, with two rows:

**Parts**

17

12

If I bind my data source to the grid, the grid automatically just uses the object's properties to create the columns, so I see columns of Label and Value:

**Label     Value**

Parts      17

Parts      12

I am assuming that I cannot achieve what I want just via xaml.  Does anyone have an example of what I am looking for?  Is it just up to me to create all of the columns during runtime programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ItemsSource[0].Label}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and code:

```
public partial class Window12 : Window
{
    public Window12()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<MyClass> l = new List<MyClass>();

        l.Add(new MyClass
        {
            Label = "Parts",
            Value = "17"
        });

        l.Add(new MyClass
        {
            Label = "Parts",
            Value = "12"
        });

        dgTest.ItemsSource = l;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post.  I am looking for a solution using the Infragistics XamDataGrid.

Comment: how is this solution helps adding variable number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Iverzin's solution will work with the XamDataGrid.  It has the ability to [autogenerate fields](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.3/CLR4.0/?page=xamData_Generating_Fields_Manually_Versus_Automatically.html), so you don't have to specify them at design-time.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered such question in another post

[Adding variable no of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958906/xamdatagrid-2011-2012-how-do-i-replace-a-fields-converter-fieldsettings-d/34528896#34528896)

In which I've created a behavior and added columns dependent on some condition(field layout no in my case). you can check datasource and then do the same.

And you do have to define some sets of columns somewhere and then retrieve them to create a FieldLayout for your XamDataGrid on basis of data source.ex.

```
        XamDataGrid xamDataGrid;
        if (DataSource.GetType() == typeof(X))
        {
            AddFieldLayout1(xamDataGrid);
        }
        else if (DataSource.GetType() == typeof(Y))
        {
            AddFieldLayout2(xamDataGrid);
        }
```

And in **AddFieldLayout** method add fields to layout of grid.